# Is there any way to manipulate the titles of a ctree plot?

Tags: r, tree, data-visualization, partitioning, party

Is there any way to change the title sizes of a ctree plot?

Use the following variables to quickly set up a ctree plot

```
a<-c(41, 45, 50, 50, 38, 42, 50, 43, 37, 22, 42, 48, 47, 48, 50, 47, 41, 50, 45, 45, 39, 45, 46, 48, 50, 47, 50, 21, 48, 50, 48, 48, 48, 46, 36, 38, 50, 39, 44, 44, 50, 49, 40, 48, 48, 45, 39, 40, 44, 39, 40, 44, 42, 39, 49, 50, 50, 48, 48, 47, 48, 47, 44, 41, 50, 47, 50, 41, 50, 44, 47, 50, 24, 40, 43, 37, 44, 32, 43, 42, 44, 38, 42, 45, 50, 47, 46, 43,
37, 47, 37, 45, 41, 50, 42, 32, 43, 48, 45, 45, 28, 44,38, 41, 45, 48, 48, 47 ,49, 16, 45, 50, 47, 50, 43, 49, 50)

X1<-c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,2,2,2,NA,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,NA,NA,2,2,2,2,NA,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,NA,NA,NA,NA,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,NA,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,NA,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,2,2,2,2,2,1,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,2,2,1,2,2,2)
X2<-c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,2,2,2,NA,NA,2,2,2,2,2,2,NA,2,2,2,2,2,NA,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,NA,NA,NA,NA,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,NA,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2)
X3<-c(NA,35,40,NA,10,NA,31,NA,14,NA,NA,15,17,NA,NA,16,10,15,14,39,17,35,14,14,22,10,15,0,34,23,13,35,32,2,14,10,14,10,10,10,40,10,13,13,10,10,10,13,13,25,10,35,NA,13,NA,10,40,0,0,20,40,10,14,40,10,10,10,10,13,10,8,NA,NA,14,NA,10,28,10,10,15,15,16,10,10,35,16,NA,NA,NA,NA,30,19,14,30,10,10,8,10,21,10,10,35,15,34,10,39,NA,10,10,6,16,10,10,10,10,34,10)
X4<-c(NA,NA,511,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,849,NA,NA,NA,NA,1324,1181,832,1005,166,204,1253,529,317,294,NA,514,801,534,1319,272,315,572,96,666,236,842,980,290,843,904,528,27,366,540,560,659,107,63,20,1184,1052,214,46,139,310,872,891,651,687,434,1115,1289,455,764,938,1188,105,757,719,1236,982,710,NA,NA,632,NA,546,747,941,1257,99,133,61,249,NA,NA,1080,NA,645,19,107,486,1198,276,777,738,1073,539,1096,686,505,104,5,55,553,1023,1333,NA,NA,969,691,1227,1059,358,991,1019,NA,1216)

p<-cbind(X1,X2,X3,X4)
```

With the following you should then get the plot below

```
library(party)  
urp<-ctree(a~., data=data.frame(a,p))
plot(urp, main = "Broken Title")
```

[image: URP example]

How do I change the title size? I've tried the following which does nothing:

```
plot(urp, main = "Broken Title",cex = 1.5)
plot(urp, main = "Broken Title",cex.main = 1.5)
```

In fact, can I manipulate the title at all? `font.main` similarly does nothing. What about the titles "Node 2" and "Node 3." Is there likewise no way for me to manipulate them?

A similar question was asked here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18817522/ctree-changing-titles-of-inner-nodes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is good news and bad news.

So the `plot()` function that's actually doing all the work there is `party:::plot.BinaryTree`. The help is available from `?plot.BinaryTree` but the bad news is it doesn't have any easily accessible parameters for font formatting. However, the good news is that the function uses grid graphics to draw to the screen and you can update properties after you've created the plot.

So after you run

```
library(party)  
urp<-ctree(a~., data=data.frame(a,p))
plot(urp, main = "Broken Title")
```

You can run

```
for(gg in grid.ls(print=F)[[1]]) {
   if (grepl("text", gg)) {
       print(paste(gg, grid.get(gg)$label,sep=": "))
   }
}
```

to see all the text boxes on the plot. For example, I see

```
[1] "GRID.text.673: Broken Title"
[1] "GRID.text.677: X1"
[1] "GRID.text.678: p = 0.03"
[1] "GRID.text.680: 1"
[1] "GRID.text.682: phantom(0) <= 1"
[1] "GRID.text.684: phantom(0) > 1"
[1] "GRID.text.686: Node 2 (n = 8)"
[1] "GRID.text.697: Node 3 (n = 109)"
```

Here i see the node names, and the text they contain. Note that the node names are not the same from plot to plot and change everything you draw the same plot. But you can use this list to find the ones you want to change and update them. So if I wanted to make the main text bigger, I would run

```
grid.edit("GRID.text.673", gp=gpar(fontsize=20))
```

or If i wanted to italize the node labels i would run

```
grid.edit("GRID.text.686", gp=gpar(fontface=3))
grid.edit("GRID.text.697", gp=gpar(fontface=3))
```

and that gives

[image]

Comment: Thank you. That all works perfectly. Since the title is always the first element in the list your code returns I can use this to instantly increase the size of the title of all hundred drastically different ctrees of mine.

Problem though: I cant seem to change the node names themselves with what you have me. If I wanted to change "Node 2" to "Group 2," what would I do?

Comment: You just need to change the `label` property rather than the `gp` settings. For example `grid.edit("GRID.text.686", label="Sub-Plot 1")` would rename the left node plot in this example.

Comment: And that's a good point, the names themselves may change, but the relative positions should be consistent between different plots with the same layout.

Comment: Hope it's okay to ask this here as I don't believe this needs another question, but how do I change the size of the rectangle objects in the grid? I've looked a gsub and it doesn't have a parameter for rectangle size.

Also, I've had problems where increasing font size makes a label overlap with other grid objects. How could I translate objects in different directions on the grid?