# How do I manipulate ctree grid elements so that the title is on two lines or so that leaf nodes become skinnier?

Tags: r, tree, data-visualization, partitioning, party

Please refer to this question to have an example to work with: [Is there any way to manipulate the titles of a ctree plot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25028312/is-there-any-way-to-manipulate-the-titles-of-a-ctree-plot)

Now, with the example ctree plot as a reference, how can I make it so that the two words that make up the title are on two different lines? I.e. I want to see the word "Broken" and then the word "Title" on a new line below the word "Broken."

I'm trying to make the boxplots skinnier. So far, the only way I've found to do this is to use:

```
png(title_file, width = w, height = h)
```

And then vary w and h until I'm happy. Unfortunately, this cuts off the title (The actual title is much longer) I think that if I could make half the title appear on the next line then everything should fit snugly (fingers-crossed).

If you however have a way for me to directly manipulate the boxplots (node 2 and node 3) and adjust their fatness without me having to adjust the width of the entire image, that would be even better.

Comment: Just running `plot(urp, main = "Broken\nTitle")` should make the plot title appear on two lines unless i'm missing something.

Comment: Yes that works. In fact I've done that before and am embarrassed that I forgot about it. Since I need to output to file I simply do:

png(title_file)
plot(urp, main = "Broken\nTitle")
dev.off()

Answer (score 0):

Notice that this is in the Details section of `?plot.BinaryTree`:

```
... additional arguments passed to callies.
```

I understood that to mean "callees", namely functins called by that plot method. The second component of the question is probably answered by following the link to node_boxplot from the `?plot.BinaryTree` help page:

```
node_barplot(ctreeobj, col = "black", fill = NULL, beside = NULL,
  ymax = NULL, ylines = NULL, widths = 1, gap = NULL, 
  reverse = NULL, id = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you, that definitely got me on the right track, but none of the functions in the documentation seem to alter the terminal boxplot width. Note that I have boxplots, so node_barplot is probably not what I need.

I looked at node_boxplot(ctreeobj, col = "black", fill = "lightgray", width = 0.5,  yscale = NULL, ylines = 3, cex = 0.5, id = TRUE) and changing width here changes the boxplot's width without changing the width of the borders of the node it is in. I need the terminal nodes itself to have decreased width (not just the boxplots inside) and there seems to be no way of doing this.

Comment: I also looked at node_terminal(ctreeobj, digits = 3, abbreviate = FALSE, fill = c("lightgray", "white"), id = TRUE)

Sadly, it does not take any parameter that seems to allow me to control terminal node width :(